# Matching string for row in csv file

Tags: python, csv

This script almost works. However it never matches, and when it does, the values are incorrect. Example:

```
no match
Lower 117, $331.50, F, 8, 193
Upper 218, $155.00, AA, 8, 195

match
Floor 6, $273.00, N, 2, 195
SECTION,PRICE,ROW,QTY,DYSLSTED
```

So I'm not sure why it isn't working. After all the values from the html file are loaded in the first time, the  program should only output `match` for even list, since they would all be in the csv. But when I run it in the current configuration, the opposite result is true.

HTML FILE `eagles.html` is [here](https://pastebin.com/BjpWEnpW)

Here is my script:

```
import os
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml.html as lh
import csv


soup = BeautifulSoup(open("eagles.html"), "lxml")
###################################################################
variable = 'test_csv_1' ########DELETE
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
file_path = (dir_path+'\Sheets')
try:
    os.makedirs(file_path)
except:
    pass
#######################
for mytable in soup.find_all('table'):
    for trs in mytable.find_all('tr'):
        tds = trs.find_all('td')
        row1 = [elem.text.strip() for elem in tds]
        row = str(row1)
        cool = row.replace("[", "")
        coolp = cool.replace("]", "")
        cool2 = coolp.replace("'", "")
        cool3 = cool2.replace(" , ", "")
        row = cool3
        rowtest = (row.split(','))
        if len(rowtest) != 5:
            rowtest = ['NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL']
        ###TABLE STUFF###
        rowtest0 = rowtest[:4] # LISTING WITHOUT DAYS LISTED
        rowtest1 = rowtest[0:1] # SECTION LOCATION
        rowtest2 = rowtest[1:2] # TICKET PRICE
        rowtest3 = rowtest[2:3] # ROW
        rowtest4 = rowtest[3:4] # TICKET QTY  
        rowtest5 = rowtest[4:5] # DAYS LISTED
        ###TABLE STUFF#
        ###CREATE CSV HEADER###
        with open(file_path+'\\'+variable+'.csv', 'a+') as headercsv:
            if os.stat(file_path+'\\'+variable+'.csv').st_size == 0:
                writer = csv.writer(headercsv)
                writer.writerow(["SECTION", "PRICE", "ROW", "QTY", "DYSLSTED"])
                print('CREATED HEADERS FOR NEW FILE')
            else:
                pass
        ###WRITE TO CSV###
        with open(file_path+'\\'+variable+'.csv', 'r') as rowin:
            if rowtest == ['NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL']:
                continue
            else:
                pass
            for boogie in rowin:
                if row in boogie:
                    print(row)
                    print(boogie)
                    print('match')
                    break
                else:
                    print(row)
                    print(boogie)
                    print('no match')
                    with open(file_path+'\\'+variable+'.csv', 'a+') as ruts:
                        writer = csv.writer(ruts)
                        writer.writerow(rowtest)
```

Comment: Please provide a **minimal** [mcve]. For example, we shouldn't need all those modules installed to run your example.

Comment: sorry forgot about those, removed irrelevant libs

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what the script is trying to do. It would help if you also showed what the output should be for the file you have given (at least the start of it).